# Installed PHP-FANN on Homestead, can't find fann.so

Tags: laravel, homestead, fann

I installed PHP-FANN on laravel/homestead version '8.1.0' by the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libfann-dev
```

After that fann.so should add to php extension directory, but i cant find it. 
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

That is only part of the process,

```
sudo pecl install fann
```

or use remmi's repo and install it that way.